# How to override path used in form_for in Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have model `DigitalAsset` and controller `Assets` (in routes `resources :assets`). When I writing `form_for DigitalAsset.new` it tries to call `digital_assets_path`. How can I override this behaviour (e.g. call `assets_path`).

Also when i using something like `f.input :test` it creates element with name `digital_asset[test]` instead of `asset[test]`. How can I change this too?

UPDATE: I've found that it gets its name from `ActionController::RecordIdentifier.singular_class_name`. Anyway should I override it for just one model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the form, you can use the parameter `:url` (see [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for))

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit ugly. Anyway it not solves problem with form fields.

Comment: @sl_bug look at the `:as` or `:namespace` options of `form_for`, it may be what you need.